# How to clear pending VCS changes in TeamCity 7+?

Tags: svn, teamcity

We have a project configured in TeamCity 7.+ to watch a project in Subversion.  Each check-in will trigger a build.  However, in this case, we want to skip/clear the backlog.

To be very clear: I do not wish to "undo" these Subversion commits.  I want to keep the svn commits, but skip the TeamCity builds.

I tried disconnecting the Build Trigger (disable, then delete), but no luck.  The TeamCity queue remains.

How to do it?  My googling skills are failing me.  =(

[image]

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: yes please. i have 46 pending builds on one branch and so far have to clear them one by one each showing a confirmation alert!

Comment: We are in 2018 and this issue was not solved.

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude certain folders/files by editing your `Checkout Rules` for your `VCS Root` in `Version Control Settings`. However, this would exclude those folders/files indefinitely.

It sounds like you only want to exclude these 4 specific changes? That seems counter intuitive as the point of Teamcity and builds in general is to build the solution/project as it is.

If you need these four changes to not be incorporated in the build, you would need to roll them back. If they are used in a different build, you would need to exclude them from this build and create a new build where these changes are needed.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this jetbrains support post](https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206621709-Reset-pending-changes), you can just detach the VCS Root and re-attach it.

Comment: I just tried this with 9.1.7 and it didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to remove the pending changes reminder from your window for these 4 specific changes, and then continue as normal (these 4 changes being incorporated silently into your next build) then the only potential solution I can think of is altering your VCS root to point somewhere else, and then to point back. This may of course not work. adding a new VCS root pointing to the same place may work in place of the above, if that is required.

If there is something different going on, e.g. you don't want these changes to trigger 4 builds, they wont, they will all go on to the next build. If, alternatively, you don't want any builds until some further changes are made, those changes wont trigger further builds once the builds have been removed from the queue (unless this behaviour has recently changed)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this by updating Triggers > VCS trigger settings > "Per-checkin Triggering" section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to disable all build steps and run.

[image: Diable build step]

Comment: You can paste image in answer